# Managing printer drivers in Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

How do I manage printer drivers on Windows Server 2003? I have 30 client computers, and I admin?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "managing" the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Install all printers on your Windows Server 2003 and then point your client computers
to your Windows Print Server.

**[Managing Printers with Windows Server 2003 R2](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Managing-Printers-Windows-Server-2003-R2.html)**

Use Group Policy to deploy printers to your client computers.

**[Deploying Printers With Group Policy in Windows Server 2003 R2](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Deploying-Printers-Group-Policy-Windows-R2.html)**

I've come across an environment where people were sharing printers from other workstations 
and they even had the same printer three times from different people just in case someone's computer goes offline.